# JasminSMS configuration

Tags: sms, jasmin-sms, smscaster

I successfully installed JasminSMS on Ubuntu, added SMS provider informations such as hostname, port, user and password, but failed to receive test SMS using HTTP API:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1401/send?username=foo&password=bar&to=*********&content=hello
```

I'm writing my own number, but I don't receive it. What other configuration do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario (you want to terminate an SMS message by using Jasmin's HTTP API) you need:

- Jasmin SMS Gateway installed
- An HTTP user configured in Jasmin SMS (this can be done in the included CLI)
- An SMPP connector configured in Jasmin SMS to connect to an SMS service provider. The credentials will be supplied by your SMS vendor of choice.
- A routing rule in Jasmin SMS Gateway to decide which SMPP connector to use

This is all well-documented here https://docs.jasminsms.com/en/latest/installation/index.html#sending-your-first-sms

If your HTTP API call is successful you'll receive an HTTP success code (200) and a GUID. Jasmin SMS then tries to deliver the SMS message via the SMPP connector (according to the routing rule configured). If your SMS message was not received you need to look into the used SMPP-connector to troubleshoot further. If the message has been accepted by the SMPP connector of choice you'll have to contact your SMPP vendor and ask them to look into the possible delivery issues.

An SMS vendor is basically a company with agreements to various operators & aggregators around the world specializing in delivering SMS messages globally (or locally of course depending on their focus) for a price.

Answer (score 0):

make sure u enter the smsc creditntials on the smpp connector and mae sure it is started(smppccm -1 cid) and check its sessision if it is bound smppccm -l